# Component not responding in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, jsx

I am having some issues with one of my components. In my program, I have my App component, which is the parent component. In it are components called Button and Inputs. In my program, you have to click one of the buttons, which are rendered by the renderButtons() function to have the Inputs component mount. When one of the buttons are clicked, the onSubmit() function is ran and the createTextBoxes() function runs at the same time. In a nutshell, the onSubmit() changes the "index" key in the state, and when the createTextBoxes() realizes that "index" has changed, it mounts the Inputs component.

The App.js code is shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Button from "./Button";
import Inputs from "./Inputs";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    index: "",
    buttons: [
      { value: "Algebra 2 Honors", classes: "primary" },
      { value: "British Literature", classes: "success" },
      { value: "Chemistry Honors", classes: "danger" },
      { value: "Modern European History", classes: "warning" },
      { value: "Spanish II", classes: "secondary" },
      { value: "Health Upper School", classes: "info" }
    ],
    textBoxes: [
      {
        identification: "Algebra 2 Honors",
        categories: [
          { Homework: 25 },
          { Notebook: 5 },
          { Quizzes: 20 },
          { Tests: 50 }
        ]
      },
      {
        identification: "British Literature",
        categories: [{ Assessments: 90 }, { Participation: 10 }]
      },
      {
        identification: "Chemistry Honors",
        categories: [
          { Homework: 25 },
          { Labreports: 34 },
          { Quizzes: 10 },
          { Tests: 31 }
        ]
      },
      {
        identification: "Modern European History",
        categories: [
          { Homework: 30 },
          { Participation: 10 },
          { Quizzes: 20 },
          { Tests: 40 }
        ]
      },
      {
        identification: "Spanish II",
        categories: [
          { Participation: 25 },
          { Projects: 25 },
          { Tests: 15 },
          { Assessments: 35 }
        ]
      },
      {
        identification: "Health Upper School",
        categories: [
          { Project: 33.333 },
          { Participation: 33.333 },
          { Quizzes: 33.333 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  renderButtons = () => {
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.buttons.length; i++) {
      const id = this.state.buttons[i].classes;
      list.push(
        <Button
          key={id}
          className={id}
          value={this.state.buttons[i].value}
          eventHandler={() => this.onSubmit(id)}
        />
      );
    }
    return list;
  };

  onSubmit = id => {
    const buttonType = id;
    var index = null;
    if (id === "primary") {
      index = 0;
    } else if (id === "success") {
      index = 1;
    } else if (id === "danger") {
      index = 2;
    } else if (id === "warning") {
      index = 3;
    } else if (id === "secondary") {
      index = 4;
    } else if (id === "info") {
      index = 5;
    }
    console.log("The button that has been clicked has an index of " + index);
    this.setState({ index });
  };

  createTextBoxes = () => {
    if (this.state.index !== "") {
      const index = parseInt(this.state.index);
      const indexPhrase = this.state.textBoxes[index];
      console.log(indexPhrase);
      return <Inputs teamState={indexPhrase} />;
    } else {
      console.log("Wait for the click of a button");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <h1 className="text-white">
          <u>Subject Grade Calculator!</u>
        </h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.renderButtons()}
        {this.createTextBoxes()}
        {/* {this.resetIndex()} */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The Button.js code is shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Button extends Component {
  state = {
    class: "btn btn-" + this.props.className,
    value: this.props.value,
    eventHandler: this.props.eventHandler
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          name="0"
          value={this.state.value}
          className={this.state.class}
          onClick={this.state.eventHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

Finally, here is the Inputs.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Inputs extends Component {
  state = {
    title: this.props.teamState.identification,
    caption:
      "Enter your information below when the text boxes prompt you to do so:"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        {console.log(this.state.object)}
        <br />
        <br />
        <h3 className="text-white">{this.state.title}</h3>
        <br />
        <h4 className="text-white">{this.state.caption}</h4>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Inputs;
```

This works fine, however, if you click on another button again, the new Inputs component with the different properties does not mount.

Can anyone please explain why the createTextBoxes() not change the component being rendered, and how I can do this?

Comment: Sidenote: do you really need to load jQuery, Bootstrap and popper in *every* component? Seems ripe for centralisation.

Comment: Try directly consuming the `props` object instead of saving to 'state' in the constructor.  What you're doing isn't the pattern react has established.

Comment: jonrsharpe you are exactly right. I will only keep it in the main html file from now on. Thanks!

Comment: Drew Reese could you give me an example of how that would work exactly, or more specifically where to implement it in my code since I am not sure if I am completely understanding what you are trying to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, me being a beginner, I did not really think about the lifecycle hooks and other functions available. All I needed to do was use the componentWillReceiveProps() function which would allow React to update the state when the new props are delivered to the Inputs Component itself. Here is the updated code for the Inputs Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Inputs extends Component {
  state = {
    title: this.props.teamState.identification,
    caption:
      "Enter your information below when the text boxes prompt you to do so:"
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props !== nextProps) {
      this.setState({ title: nextProps.teamState.identification });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {console.log(this.state)}
        <br />
        <br />
        <h3 className="text-white">{this.state.title}</h3>
        <br />
        <h4 className="text-white">{this.state.caption}</h4>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Inputs;
```

I have removed the bootstrap, jquery, and popper links as requested or suggested by the user jonrsharpe. However, this function is not going to be available in version 17 of React so it is recommended to use UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() instead. Here is the link to where I figured out this information: [1](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) Thanks!